# Windows Mobile Development Under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, windows-mobile, mobile

I'm developing applications for iPhone and Android on my Mac, but now I want to port them to Windows Mobile. I know that it requires Visual Studio, but that's just if you want to make .Net applications. Then I want to know if there is any alternative, something like Mono...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 (unlike Windows Mobile) is quite a closed system with one development environment supported. I.e. you are stuck with Visual Studio and, consequently, Windows.

Update: Windows Mobile 6.x is not much better for MacOS developer. For .NET CF you use Visuaal Studio 2005 or 2008. For native code development you could use Visual Studio 2005 (if memory serves) or, before it, there existed eMbedded Visual Studio 4 (and embedded visual tools 3 earlier), both being similar to Visual Studio 6 (and probably built using the same code base).

Alternatives included FreePascal (Pascal language, native code compilation) and NSBasic (interpreted BASIC language, if memory serves).

But all those tools were for Windows only.

Comment: I'm talking about Windows Mobile, not Windows Phone 7 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Visual Studio for both managed and native Windows Mobile applications. I don't think Mono supports .NETCF and I don't think SharpDevelop does either.

You might need to install a Windows virtual machine to run on your Mac. Or... get a PC for Windows development. I have both a PC and Mac workstation on my desk since I do iPhone, Android, and .NET all together.

Comment: Yeah, I have a PC workstation too, but I want to retire all my Windows stuff and go straight to Mac forever

Answer (score 1):

I am actually looking at starting a project to do this using Mono and Moonlight. Granted, I am in the very early stages of research but I think that it can be done and I am hoping to start getting some people together to help in the near future. I will post the github repo back here when I get something going.

Answer (score 0):

PLease have a look into this
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/12/21/how-to-develop-for-windows-phone-8-on-your-mac.aspx

there is this Visual studio code which can be leveraged to initiate and test some basic wiMo app development